# VMWare Revert Non Persistent Disk on Restart

Tags: vmware-server, scheduled-task

I have a Virtual Machine running Windows 2003 Server which itself is running on VMWare Server 1.0.4.

The Virtual Machine has Non-Persistent Disks and periodically I manually shut down the box and turn it back on in order to put it back to it's original state.

Can anyone tell me how I can schedule this to happen on a weekly basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script it.

Either by using the fairly simplistic `vmware-cmd` or the more sophisticated APIs.

There is some documentation on the VMware site - [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html).